# ¿Usar get y set o declarar la variable publica?

Tags: java

Muchas veces las variables de una clase en java se declaran como privadas para tener encapsulamiento.

Otras de las cuestiones para declarar una variable como privada es para que sólo pueda ser accesible desde la misma clase, pero finalmente en la mayoría de los casos se termina haciendo métodos **set** y **get** para modifcar la variable o para obtenerla fuera de la clase.

Entonces lo que me pregunto es si hay algún buen motivo para declarar una variable privada y ponerle **set** y **get** en vez de declararla publica y evitarse un **set** y un **get**.

Comment: Excelente pregunta, tal vez demasiado amplia, pero común entre aquellos que aprenden el paradigma de programación orientada a objetos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Permitir el acceso libre a los atributos de la clase no es un diseño condenado, solo es diferente. Usualmente se evita esto a modo de que la clase maneje al interno cualquier lógica de negocio que pueda asociar a los campos. Pör poner un ejemplo:

```
public class Foo {
    public List<String> listaNombres;
    public Foo() {
        listaNombres = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Friky", "Luiggi"));
    }
}

public class Otro {
    public List<String> listaNombresOtro;
    public void obtieneDeFoo(Foo foo) {
        listaNombresOtro = foo.listaNombres;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.listaNombres);
        Otro otro = new Otro();
        otro.obtieneDeFoo(foo);
        otro.listaNombresOtro.set(0, "Cambio");
        System.out.println(foo.listaNombres);
        System.out.println(otro.listaNombresOtro);
    }
}
```

Si luego quisiéramos agregar validaciones para este código, se complica la situación. Claro, en el ejemplo anterior no se puede ver porque solo hay unas 3 llamadas a `Foo#listaNombres`, pero si estuviese disperso a través de decenas de métodos la situación se complica. Además, también complica si se cambiase la definición del atributo (nombre, tipo, etc), por todos los cambios que se harían. Un problema adicional es que al obtener la lista de `Foo#listaNombres` no queremos pasar la lista directamente, en su lugar queremos una copia de ella. Podríamos hacer la copia en cada ubicación de `foo.listaNombres` pero eso lleva a código duplicado (bueno, multiplicado más que duplicado).

---

El uso de los métodos `get` y `set` (de preferencia públicos) está acorde a la [especificación JavaBean](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1485219027_8cbd3e9a42d5e9ef8bd1a4d30ee42b4a):

> 7 Properties
>
> Properties are discrete, named attributes of a Java Bean that can
>   affect its appearance or its behavior. For example, a GUI button might
>   have a property named “Label” that represents the text displayed in
>   the button.
>
> Properties show up in a number of ways:
>
> Properties may be exposed in scripting environments as though they
>   were fields of objects. So in a Javascript environment I might do
>   “b.Label = foo” to set the value of a property. Properties can be
>   accessed programmatically by other components calling their getter and
>   setter methods (see Section 7.1 below). (...)
>
> 7.1 Accessor methods
>
> Properties are always accessed via method calls on their owning
>   object. For readable properties there will be a getter method to read
>   the property value. For writable properties there will be a setter
>   method to allow the property value to be updated.

Traducido:

> 7 Propiedades
>
> Las propiedades son atributos discretos y con nombre de un Java Bean que puede afectar su apariencia o comportamiento. Por ejemplo, un botón GUI podría tener una propiedad llamada "Label" que represente el texto que se muestra en el botón.
>
> Las propiedades se muestras de varias maneras:
>
> Las propiedades se pueden exponer en ambientes de script como si fuesen campos de objetos. Así, en un ambiente JavaScript podría hacer "b.Label = foo" para asignar el valor de una propiedad. Las propiedades pueden ser accedidas programáticamente por otros componentes que llaman a sus métodos get y set (mirar la sección 7.1 debajo). (...)
>
> 7.1 Métodos de acceso
>
> Siempre se accede a las propiedades a través de llamadas a métodos en el objeto que las posee. Para propiedades que se pueden leer, existirá un método get para leer el valor de la propiedad. Para propiedades que se pueden escribir, existirá un método set que permite actualizar el valor de la propiedad.

Esto significa que los métodos get y set permiten el acceso a las propiedades (atributos) de una clase. Muchos frameworks se benefician de esta definición. Por mencionar algunos:

- Spring, CDI, Guice (IoC, inyección de dependencias)
- Hibernate, MyBatis (acceso a datos)
- XStream, Jackson, Gson (conversión entre objetos y JSON, XML y otros formatos)
- Spring MVC, JSF, Expression Language, JSTL, etc (web MVC)
- JavaFX (GUI de escritorio)
- Metro, Apache CXF, Apache Axis (implementación/consumo de servicios Web)
- Etc. O mejor dicho: cualquier framework que trabaje los objetos usando reflexión (reflection) que normalmente se basa en usar clases con constructores por defecto y acceso a los atributos mediante métodos get y set.

Colocando un ejemplo de Spring con configuración XML:

```xml
<bean id="fooBean" class="paquete.de.mis.clases.Foo">
    <property name="listaNombres">
        <list>
            <value>Friky</value>
            <value>Luiggi</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

La clase Java asociada a este bean:

```
package paquete.de.mis.clases;

public class Foo {
    private List<String> listaNombres;
    public List<String> getListaNombres() {
        return this.listaNombres;
    }
    //permite a Spring asignar el valor de la lista mediante reflexión
    public void setListaNombres(List<String> listaNombres) {
        this.listaNombres = listaNombres;
    }
}
```

Ejemplo en JSF para la asociación de cambpos usando Expression Language:

```xhtml
<!-- permite a JSF llamar al getter mediante reflexión -->
<h:dataTable value="#{foo.listaNombres}" var="nombre">
    <h:column>
        #{nombre}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

La clase Java asociada:

```
package paquete.de.mis.managedbeans;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Foo {
    private List<String> listaNombres;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listaNombres = new List<>();
        listaNombres.add("Friky");
        listaNombres.add("Luiggi");
    }
    public List<String> getListaNombres() {
        return this.listaNombres;
    }
    public void setListaNombres(List<String> listaNombres) {
        this.listaNombres = listaNombres;
    }
}
```

Además, lo "bueno" (¿?) de usar estos métodos es que puedes agregar lógica de negocio en ellos para evitar el contacto directo con los objetos con los que interactúas. Del caso anterior que indicamos que se quiere obtener una copia de la lista en lugar de obtener la lista directamente, podríamos agregar dicha lógica en el método get:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<String> listaNombres;
    public List<String> getListaNombres() {
        //en lugar de devolver la lista directamente
        //devolvemos una nueva lista con los elementos
        //de mi lista actual
        return new ArrayList<>(this.listaNombres);
    }
}
```

Si te parece mucho esfuerzo generar el código de estos métodos, puedes usar [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) que ofrece facilidades para agregar estos métodos mediante anotaciones en tu código, entre otros beneficios.

---

Adaptado de [Private List with Getter/Setter vs Public List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983828/1065197)

Comment: Quizás sería útil de mencionar que ventajas tiene el paradigma de desarrollo con `JavaBean` s?

Comment: @StefanNolde la mención a los frameworks lo hace.

Comment: Claro, el valor de un IOC-framework se entiende cuando uno lo usa, solamente pensaba que esta pregunta podría interesar gente ya mucho antes que empiezan a trabajar a este nivel de desarrollo.

Comment: @Stefan creo que no entiendo esta parte de tu comentario: "pensaba que esta pregunta podría interesar gente ya mucho antes que empiezan a trabajar a este nivel de desarrollo". ¿Te refieres a que las respuestas deberían estar orientadas más a gente que aún no ve esos frameworks? Indícame por favor, a veces la traducción a español nos juega mal.

Comment: No, para mi una respuesta no **debe** ser nada mas que útil y correcto, para orientarse al nivel de conocimiento existe la posibilidad de tener una variedad de respuestas a distintos niveles. Yo solamente pensaba que el concepto de JavaBeans es útil para la diseño modular ya antes de conocer y entender estos frameworks.

Comment: @StefanNolde ah no, no lo es. El beneficio principal que yo le he encontrado es por el uso de estos frameworks. Sino, haría mi código más sencillo y no usaría getters/setters.

Comment: XD "No lo es" es una fuerte declaración. Y no estoy de acuerdo, creo depende del proyecto concreto, a veces es mejor, a veces no, y trabajando con IDE básicamente no causa más trabajo usarlos.

Comment: @StefanNolde más que del proyecto, depende de la decisión de diseño. Al final, en el software, todo es relativo, no hay bala de plata ni nada escrito en piedra. Lo que funcione mejor para el equipo es lo que termina convirtiéndose en regla para el equipo, no tiene que ser compartida por toda la comunidad.

Comment: A eso me referí, de las caracteristicas del proyecto depende la decisión de diseño. Aparte 100% de acuerdo.

Comment: En el 1er codigo que escribiste, porque no creastes el constructor de la clase `Otro`? Tenia entendido que siempre hay que crear un constructor para cada clase, para inicializar sus atributos (variables)

Comment: @Michelle cuando una clase no tiene constructor, el compilador le agrega un constructor por defecto, que luce así: `public <NombreDeClase>() { }`. Es decir, es un constructor público, sin argumentos y sin contenido.

Comment: ah ya, y es invisible también cierto?

Comment: @Michelle no necesitas declararlo, el compilador lo va a hacer por ti. Si necesitas crear constructores explícitos que necesiten argumentos, los puedes hacer, pero el compilador no agregará el constructor por defecto. Lo que puedes hacer, también, es tener múltiples constructores para una clase, entre ellos el constructor por defecto.

Comment: aah bueno, gracias @LuiggiMendozaJ tu si sabes jejeje..

Answer (score 4):

Acabas de plasmar una de las preguntas más usuales de los desarrolladores, "¿Uso propiedades o accedo directamente a los atributos de la clase?" En las otras respuestas tiene buenos ejemplos, yo puedo colocar uno sencillo:

```
public class Point {
    int x = 0;
}
Point point = new Point();
point.x = 1;
```

Versus

```
public class Point {
    int x = 0;

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
Point point = new Point();
point.setX(1);
```

El segundo segmento usa propiedades para controlar el valor del atributo, pero aunque hace uso de uno de los principios básicos de la programación orientada a objetos, no tiene sentido si no requerimos (o requeriremos en un futuro) controlar las entradas/salidas de ese atributo.

No necesitas aplicar todos los conceptos teóricos que conoces a primera instancia, muchos de ellos los deberás aplicar a medida que tu aplicación madure o escale, aumenten las necesidades de control, pero la lógica del negocio te dirá si debes encapsular o no los atributos de tu clase. A veces el exceso de encapsulamiento termina creando monstruos de código como:

```
WindowManager.getInstance().getTopWindow().getInitialPoint().getX()
```

Cuando puede ser más legible como:

```
WindowManager.instance.topWindow.initialPoint.x;
```

Pero como dije antes, dependerá de la lógica de negocios de tu aplicación cuál usar.

Comment: Trata evitar formulaciones como "Arriba tiene...". Dependiente del ordenamiento de las respuestas o si a la comunidad le gusta tu respuesta, termina abajo a lo que te refieres ;) Te lo cambio a "en las otras respuestas".

Comment: No veo que aumente la legibilidad usar los campos respecto los métodos como para ser una razón para elegir una opción u otra. Si tu aplicación (o esa parte de código) puede "escalar" es mejor usar métodos desde el principio que refactorizar todo el código después.

Comment: No siempre es necesario agregar métodos de acceso a campos en una clase. en el ejemplo coloco menciono un caso muy básico coordenada (x,y) que pueden tomar cualquier valor numérico entero. Claro en casos donde necesites validar de manera estricta será necesario sus respectivos get/set.

Answer (score 2):

Si, existen buenos motivos para usarlos, aun que no deberían ser considerado universalmente necesario. Si tu declaras una variable (o *campo*) publica, permites acceso directo a su contenido sin ninguna medida de control. En muchos casos eso no tiene que ser un problema, pero con un sistema creciendo si lo puede ser.

Implementando métodos para acceder la variable te da una posibilidad de en cualquier momento agregar código que controla el acceso a la variable sin tener que cambiar la interfaz de tu clase. Te doy un ejemplo.

Consideremos esta clase:

```
public class Persona{

    public String nombre="";
    public String apellido="";
}
```

en comparacion a la version con `get` y `set`

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre="";
    private String apellido="";
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

}
```

En algun momento nos damos cuenta que tenemos que garantizar que en ningún momento nombre o apellido quedan `null`.

Con la primera clase eso es básicamente imposible, `persona.nombre = null;` es nada que podríamos prohibir. Sin embargo en la otra versión hay una manera superfácil:

```
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        if (nombre!=null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("null no permitido");
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        if (apellido!=null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("null no permitido");
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
```

y tenemos una excepción si alguien trata de colocar null.

Un ejemplo mas practico sería que hay que implementar un **sello de tiempo** para respaldar los datos de actualización. Sin getters y setters tuviéramos de asegurarnos de revisar todo el código en que los campos podrían ser modificados.
La práctica de usar setters por defecto nos permite un camino mas fácil:

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre="";
    private String apellido="";
    private long timestamp=new Date().getTime();

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        if (!this.nombre.equals(nombre)) timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        if (!this.nombre.equals(nombre)) timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public Date getActualizado(){
        return new Date(timestamp);
    }
```

Así era posible de implementar este funcionalidad solamente en el modelo en una clase.

A lo contrario, un paradigma en que getters y setters son completamente de sobra son **VO**s ( value objects, objetos de valor ) inmutables. Un ejemplo:

```
public class PersonaVO{

    public final String nombre;
    public final String apellido;

    public PersonaVO(String nombre, String apellido){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
    }
}
```

En este caso getters o setters serían completamente sin sentido.

Como ves, si, hay motivos, pero todo depende del diseño y contexto.

Comment: Respecto a esta implementación cabe mencionar que lanzar excepciones en los setters no es una práctica común y hay mucha discusión al respecto.

Comment: Por supuesto. La práctica puede ser muy util en algunos contextos, terrible en otros. Hay mejores ejemplos, pero por ahora usé este. En algún momento con más tiempo puedo editarlo para dar un mejor ejemplo.

Comment: No creo que carezca de sentido tener getters o setters si las variables son inmutables: El getter está claro que es útil para obtener la variable si no es declarada pública; el setter aunque no pueda ser asignada de nuevo sí podría ser modificada si no se trata de primitivas (se pueden cambiar las propiedades de un objeto sin asignar el objeto entero ya que controlo la lógica del método set)

Comment: @Awes0meM4n la única manera de cambiar algo en un VO con todos campos final es reflexión. Que diferencia hace si tengo getters o setters en este caso?

Comment: La misma diferencia de siempre: controlas lo que hace el método `set`. Es la parte verdaderamente fundamental de usar métodos vs campos accesibles. Por eso no pierde sentido su uso incluso cuando se usan variables finales.

Comment: Perdon, pero que quieres hacer en el método set en un VO como en este ejemplo? Tirar una excepción? Un `System.out`? Como puede ser fundamental de tener un método que en ningún caso puede hacer que su nombre indica?

Answer (score 1):

Los Get son las salidas y los Set son las entradas de la clase. **Se considera una buena práctica implementarlos por temas de seguridad principalmente** ya que hacemos máxima la encapsulación.

Aislamos la representación real de los datos y sólo tendríamos acceso al comportamiento.

Comment: No es tan simple. Si quieres demostrar como se puede aislar la representación, tienes que dar ejemplos como. Si lo dejas por defecto no te dan ninguna ventaja, ni de seguridad, ni de representación, solamente preparan practicas para implementar eso sin necesidad de cambiar la interfaz.