# Sobre un método static en una clase

Tags: java, poo, clase, método

En la siguiente clase tengo el método `getName()` el cual quería que fuese `static` porque lo iba a utilizar dentro de otro método en la misma clase `Person` (quería hacer esto: `Person.getName()`),  sin embargo cuando le puse `static` me marco el siguiente error:
`non-static variable name cannot be referenced from a static context`, una posible solucion seria quitarle el `private` a la variable `name`,

hay alguna otra solucion para este problema?

Se podria conservar `private` a la variable `name`?

```
class Person{

    private String name, gender;

    Person(String name, String gender){
        this.name=name;
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    static String getName(){//si  se le pone static marca error.
        return name;
    }

    String getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

}
```

Comment: Si lo pensabas usar en otro método dentro de la misma clase, ¿porqué quieres que sea estático? A menos que el otro miembro también vaya a ser estático, no hay razón de hacer ésa función estática.

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer: **un getter estático** es una mala idea. Te llevaría a violar al menos dos principios de la POO: el _encapsulamiento_ (tener que declarar `name` como público)  y la razón de ser de los `getter` y `setter` (poder acceder a ellos desde cualquier parte, instanciando la clase). Además, el motivo que argumentas: _porque lo iba a utilizar dentro de otro método en la misma clase_ no tiene ningún sentido... para hacer eso, el método no tiene que ser estático y en caso de que lo necesites _realmente_ tampoco debería llamarse `getName`, por convención de nombres.

Comment: Para entender mejor lo afirmado en el anterior comentario, sugiero que leas esta pregunta y sus respuestas: [¿Usar get y set o declarar la variable publica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45655/29967)

Comment: @A.Cedano y entonces como deberia de llamar al metodo `getName`, dentro de la misma clase,  en un metodo `static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explicación breve

Los miembros no estáticos le pertenecen a las instancias/objetos de una clase. Los miembros estáticos le pertenecen a la clase. Si un getter se declara estático, es general para todas las instancias de la clase y no para el valor específico para cada instancia. Como esto es inconsistente, la solución a tu problema es no usar getters estáticos para tus atributos.

---

## Explicación larga

En una clase, cuando declaras un miembro (atributo o método) como estático, significa que dicho miembro *le pertenece a la case y no a una instancia*. Esto significa que dichos miembros pueden ser accedidos sin necesidad de crear una instancia de una clase.

Ejemplo:

```
public class StringUtil {
    public static final String limpiaEspacios(String cadena) {
        return cadena == null ? null : cadena.trim();
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //no se necesita crear una instancia de StringUtil
        System.out.println(StringUtil.limpiaEspacios("hola mundo"));
        System.out.println(StringUtil.limpiaEspacios("hola mundo "));
        System.out.println(StringUtil.limpiaEspacios("    hola mundo    "));
    }
}
```

Salida

```
hola mundo
hola mundo
hola mundo
```

Dado que el miembro estático le pertenece a la clase, este no puede acceder a los miembros de instancia, puesto que los miembros de instancia pertenecen a una instancia particular (objeto) de la clase. Ejemplo:

```
public class Persona {
    private String name, gender;
    public Persona(String name, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getGender() { return this.gender; }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //se necesita crear una instancia de Persona
        Persona persona = new Persona("Luiggi", "masculino");
        System.out.println(persona.getName() + " " + persona.getGender());
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Luiggi masculino
```

Como puedes ver, los miembros estáticos se pueden considerar globales para todas las instancias de una clase, mientras que los elementos no estáticos le corresponden a cada instancia de una clase. Aquí un ejemplo que muestra las diferencias:

```
public class Contador {
    //atributo estático
    //global para todas las instancias
    private static int contadorInstancias;

    //atributo no estático
    //pertenece a cada instancia
    private int contador;

    public Contador() {
        contadorInstancias++;
    }

    public static int getContadorInstancias() {
        //ojo, no se puede usar this
        //porque el método es estático y no puede acceder
        //a los atributos no estáticos
        return contadorInstancias;
    }

    public int getContador() {
        return this.contador;
    }

    public void contar() {
        this.contador++;
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Total de instancias de Contador: " + Contador.getContadorInstancias());

        Contador contador1 = new Contador();
        contador1.contar();
        contador1.contar();
        contador1.contar();

        System.out.println("Valor de contador1: " + contador1.getContador());
        System.out.println("Total de instancias de Contador: " + Contador.getContadorInstancias());

        Contador contador2 = new Contador();
        contador2.contar();
        System.out.println("Valor de contador2: " + contador1.getContador());
        System.out.println("Valor de contador2: " + contador2.getContador());
        System.out.println("Total de instancias de Contador: " + Contador.getContadorInstancias());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Simplemente añadir que en el caso de atributos estáticos no tiene mucho sentido crear un getter público, y normalmente se deja el propio atributo público. Además la salida del último bloque de código sería muy explicativa.

Comment: @DavidDPG lo tiene si el atributo estático no es una constante y si es mutable.

Comment: Por qué le pones `return this.contador;` en lugar de `return contador;` nadamas? En este método: `public int getContador() {
        return this.contador;
    }`

Comment: @Michelle puede ir de ambas formas. El IDE lo auto genera. Además, para este caso en específico, conviene resaltar que en métodos estáticos no se puede usar `this`.

Comment: nadamas por ser estáticos ya no se puede usar `this`? , porque en el comentario `//ojo,...` se da a entender que como el método es estático, no puede acceder a variables no estáticas y por ello no se puede usar `this`, pero `contadorInstancias` sí es estatica.

Comment: Exacto. En el método `public static int getContadorInstancias()` se retorna la variable estática `contadorInstancias`. Si intentas cambiarlo a `return this.contadorInstancias;` te saldrá un error de compilación indicando que no se puede usar `this`. La palabra `this`, dentro de una clase, refiere a la instancia/objeto actual que se usa.

Comment: Ah bueno, otra pregunta, supongamos que en el metodo `getContador()` necesito introducir el resultado del método `getContadorInstancias` es decir, necesito usar la variable `contadorInstancias` en el método `getContador()`, como la llamo?

Comment: @Michelle un miembro estático puede ser usando dentro de los métodos no estáticos sin problemas. Podrías usar `public int getContador() { return this.contador + contadorInstancias; }`.

Comment: y como se asegura de que `contadorInstancias` es lo que retorno el método `getContadorInstancias`?, ¿No existe la posibilidad de  confusión entre el atributo `contadorInstancias` de la clase y la variable `contadorInstancias` que retorno el método?

Comment: ?? no entiendo tu comentario, de donde viene eso 'en un método estático no puedes devolver nunca el valor de una instancia de la clase', porque lo mencionas?

Comment: @Michelle perdón, creo que no respondí bien tu última pregunta. Sobre si existe posibilidad de confusión entre los dos atributos, pues los IDEs te marcan con distinto estilo los atributos estáticos de los no estáticos. Si no me equivoco, los ponen en itálica (cursiva), a diferencia de los no estáticos.

Comment: ora..hmm creo que no entendistes mi pregunta

Comment: @Michelle [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66037/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-j-and-michelle).

Answer (score 2):

Los métodos estáticos solo pueden acceder a datos estáticos.

Los datos `name`, `gender` son variables de una *instancia* de la clase *Person*, no puedes saberlos a menos que hagas un `new Person("Pedro","H");`

Imagina en la "vida real"... sabes lo que es una *Persona*, que harías si yo te pido "Dame el nombre de la persona"... me preguntarías **¿cuál persona?**
Ah! pero hay *una persona* que se llama Michelle y hay *otra persona* que se llama Octavio, ésas son instancias de Personas.